# Solving "Document must be a JSON object"

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic-framework, couchdb

I'm beginning to learn Ionic/Angular by creating a todo app, which uses couchdb/pouchdb to store its data. I created a Todo model which is defined as below :

```
export class TodoModel {
    _id : string;
    title : string;
    description: string;

    constructor(_id : string, title: string, description: string){
        this._id=_id;
        this.title=title;
        this.description=description;

    }
}
```

I understand that I have to convert my todo object to a JSON object so I'm trying this :

```
  todoToJson(todo : TodoModel): string{
    let todoJson =JSON.stringify(todo);
    console.log(typeof(todoJson));
    console.log(todoJson);
    return todoJson;

  }

  createTodo(todo : TodoModel) {
    this.db.put(this.todoToJson(todo));
  }
```

But when I actually try to use these functions, I get this in my console : 
[image]

Here's where I'm confused, my first console.log tells me that my object is a string (and Json are strings right?), and the result of the second is (to me) a Json, which is [correctly interpreted by a json editor](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=f6dcaf022831432e9454c6a005486f24), so what am I doing wrong ?

I'm posting quickly before going to work, I may forget a few details so let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: `JSON object` Huh, looks like they don't get it either. But you're trying to `stringify` the object twice in `todoToJson` (object => string => string??)  - try stringifying it only once?

Comment: Oh I see, I changed the return in todoToJson to "     return todoJson;  " but I still get the same error :/

Comment: If that doesn't fix the problem, please edit that into your question

Comment: If I understand correctly, put() wants an object, not a string. Try not stringifying but just giving it the object you want to store?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen That's working ! Thanks a lot, but I now don't get what is the difference between a Json object and string ?  was I wrong when I said "(and Json are strings right?)" ?

Comment: You're completely right - JSON is a *particular way of formatting a string to represent a Javascript object*. Something that is JSON is a string. Something that is an object is not JSON. It's a common misunderstanding - that's why I said `Huh, looks like they don't get it either` up above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't just pass the object into the put function?

```
createTodo(todo : TodoModel) {
    this.db.put(todo);
}
```

Comment: Because I thought a Json object was a string, It's working like that, as proposed @SamiKuhmomen too, i'm accepting yours as the answer since his is a comment ;)

Comment: Classes in typescript always behave like JSON objects in typescript. They only need to be stringified when you need a string type operation. Thanks btw :)